# I have an array X with values of node representing there groups. if I have n groups how to assign unique color to each group?

Tags: python

My array

```
X = [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I am drawing a graph where each node X [i] is connected to each other. I wanted to assign a unique color to all nodes belonging to a particular group.

Can you please suggest a Python code to assign colors?
I have tried this way but it can not be generalize to n groups.

```py
color_map = []
for i in X:
    if i==0:
        color_map.append('blue')
    elif i==1:
        color_map.append('yellow')
    else: 
        color_map.append('green')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a color map and then translate each number to its corresponding color:

```py
colors = {
    0: 'blue',
    1: 'yellow',
    2: 'green',
}
mapped = [colors[i] for i in X]
```

To extend the solution, you simply add more values to the color map.